# How to access values inside sub class object?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, vtigercrm

I have sub class and i want access value, but I do not know how and I am a beginner in php programming.

code in php :

```
function initDisplay($parent) {  // $parent type Vtiger_PDF_Generator 
    $pdf = $parent->getPDF();
    $contentFrame = $parent->getContentFrame();
```

The following details of Vtiger_PDF_Generator :

```
Vtiger_PDF_Generator object {
 headerViewer => Vtiger_PDF_InventoryHeaderViewer object {
model => Vtiger_PDF_Model object {
  values => array(2) (
  ) ....
```

i want get value array in sub class Vtiger_PDF_Model from parent class Vtiger_PDF_Generator.

I attach image to clarify this problem [image]

Please guide me, Thanks.

Comment: Assuming these are public accessible you can do $parent->headerViewer->model->values[0]->title to get the first item of array or you can loop $parent->headerViewer->model->values

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these variable are public accessible you can access first item of the values array,

`$parent->headerViewer->model->values[0]->title`

or you can loop

```
$valuesArray= $parent->headerViewer->model->values;
foreach ($valuesArray as $value)
{
  echo $value->title;
}
```